# Regular expression not matching

Tags: java, regex, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to write a small program that extract information from a website. I only want to get certain information that is in between two strings, "ORIGIN" and "//". Im not getting any errors in the code but I'm unable to print the info to screen for some reason. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.util.regex.*;


class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?val=293762&db=nuccore&dopt=genbank&extrafeat=976&fmt_mask=0&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&log$=seqview&maxplex=3&maxdownloadsize=1000000").get();

        String text = doc.text();
        String pattern1 = "ORIGIN";  
        String pattern2 = "//";
        String regexString = Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString, Pattern.MULTILINE); 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);


        while (matcher.find()) {
            String textInBetween = matcher.group(1); 
        }

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `DOTALL` flag to match any possible newline characters

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + 
                            Pattern.quote(pattern2), Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Ok so I also have change the regex to match everything between the two strings excluding digits by changing the regex to "([^0-9](.*?)) obviously this is incorrect because it doesn't seem to do anything. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the patterns with `DOTALL` modifier:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL); 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2), Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This modifier allows the period `.` to match every character including new lines. Without them, dot matches every character *except for* new lines.